# load / autopolulate all images from local folder using js / jquery during compile time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

recently i managed to get a js code to autopopulate all images in a file. below are the html and js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$("div").each( function(i) {
 $(this).append("<img src='images/"+(++i)+".png' width='79' height='79' />");
});

});

<body>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
</body>
```

Source: https://technotip.com/2133/dynamically-load-images-jquery-looping/

from responsivenesss and dynamic perspective, theres 2 issue

1. i have to set the no of div tags according to no of img in the folder. how do i set the html markup according to no of img? eg if theres 5 img in the folder, i want it to 'create' itself 5 div tags, n so on. i dont need to keep changing the no of div tags everytime no of img changes.
2. from the js, it seems that it will read the img having numbered file name, starting from 1. currently i have 5 img, having file name 1,2,3,4,5. if i wana add 100 more, i have to rename to 6,7,8,.....104,105. thats not efficient. how do i make it read all imgs regardless of that the file name is? using js / jquery if possible...

thank you

Comment: You can send an Ajax request to the server and request all the images and automatically enter the images with the return information. I can enter the asp mvc code for you. What language do you use on the server side?

Comment: @meysamasadi not using server, just plain html css js for now.. this is basically getting from my local directory. if possible i would try to stick to using js or jquery functions